# Do i have to clean lists inside an object that is not used anymore?

Tags: java

I'm creating an object that is `Event.class` and this event run like a game event for X minutes.
The Player participates and it runs and then it finishes. I store this Object in a `EventManager.java` and when it's done I release it from `EventManager.java`

I guess GC is coming to finish this Object after a while since it's not used. What about the lists that this `Event.class` is using. The places that are still in there I must clean those lists (will this block the action of the garbage collector) or it will go away anyway since it's not saved - assigned anywhere?

Comment: Unless you maintain references to the lists elsewhere, they will also be garbage-collected

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't worry about them. once the `Event.class` is released the list will be unreferenced and will be allegeable for the GC to be collected. Unless, as mentioned, you have are holding a ref to those list somewhere else.